# jQuery get previous position of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I looking for a way to find out previous place of element before `append`, I have 50 element that should append to different elements but in a certain statement, the question is how can I find previous location of each element?

```js
$('#statment').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val === "0") {
    $('#text1').appendTo('#target');
    $('#text2').appendTo('#target');
  } else if (val === "1") {
    $('#text1').appendTo('#old');
    $('#text2').appendTo('#old');
    // Detect previous place??
  }
});
```

```css
#target {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#old {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="statment" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="1" />

<div id="target"></div>

<div id="old">
<a id="text1">Text 1</a>
<a id="text2">Text 1</a>
</div>
```

This is just a sample of my real code, the real code is too large for share.

I need in `else` instead of bring back each element to old parent, detect previous position of each element. Is it possible?

`$('#text1').appendTo('#target');` so how can I find the origin position of this element?

Comment: You'll need to store the old `.parent()` element somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to leave a "trace" in the original location when you move the element away from it. Like an empty `<span>` that has an attribute referring to the element that was there.

Here is how that could work:

```js
$('#statment').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val === "0") {
    $('#text1,#text2').each(function () {
      // Only move the element when it is not yet within the target area
      if (!$(this).closest("#target").length) { 
        $(this).wrap($('<span>').attr("data-ref", this.id)).appendTo('#target');
      }
    });
  } else if (val === "1") {
    $('span[data-ref]').each(function () {
      $(this).replaceWith($('#' + $(this).data("ref")));
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#target {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.old {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="statment" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="1" />

<div id="target"></div>

<div class="old">
  <a id="text1">Text 1</a>
</div>
<div class="old">
  <a id="text2">Text 2</a>
</div>
```